# Using spacy in R Markdown with reticulate

Tags: python, r, r-markdown, spacy, reticulate

I am trying to use `spacy` in a R Markdown document. Everything seems to work except the rendering using `displacy`. This is the code chunk I'm using:

````
```{python}
from spacy import displacy
doc = nlp("My name is Dhiraj.")
displacy.render(doc)
```
````

When I knit the document or even if I execute the code chunk, I don't see the svg with the arrow heads. Instead this is the output on executing the above code chunk:

```
'<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="127-0" class="displacy" width="750" height="224.5" style="max-width: none; height: 224.5px; color: #000000; background: #ffffff; font-family: Arial">\n<text class="displacy-token" fill="currentColor" text-anchor="middle" y="134.5">\n    <tspan class="displacy-word" fill="currentColor" x="50">My</tspan>\n    <tspan class="displacy-tag" dy="2em" fill="currentColor" x="50">ADJ</tspan>\n</text>\n\n<text class="displacy-token" fill="currentColor" text-anchor="middle" y="134.5">\n    <tspan class="displacy-word" fill="currentColor" x="225">name</tspan>\n    <tspan class="displacy-tag" dy="2em" fill="currentColor" x="225">NOUN</tspan>\n</text>\n\n<text class="displacy-token" fill="currentColor" text-anchor="middle" y="134.5">\n    <tspan class="displacy-word" fill="currentColor" x="400">is</tspan>\n    <tspan class="displacy-tag" dy="2em" fill="currentColor" x="400">VERB</tspan>\n</text>\n\n<text class="displacy-token" fill="currentColor" text-anchor="middle" y="134.5">\n    <tspan class="displacy-word" fill="currentColor" x="575">Dhiraj.</tspan>\n    <tspan class="displacy-tag" dy="2em" fill="currentColor" x="575">PROPN</tspan>\n</text>\n\n<g class="displacy-arrow">\n    <path class="displacy-arc" id="arrow-127-0-0" stroke-width="2px" d="M70,89.5 C70,2.0 225.0,2.0 225.0,89.5" fill="none" stroke="currentColor"/>\n    <text dy="1.25em" style="font-size: 0.8em; letter-spacing: 1px">\n        <textPath xlink:href="#arrow-127-0-0" class="displacy-label" startOffset="50%" fill="currentColor" text-anchor="middle">poss</textPath>\n    </text>\n    <path class="displacy-arrowhead" d="M70,91.5 L62,79.5 78,79.5" fill="currentColor"/>\n</g>\n\n<g class="displacy-arrow">\n    <path class="displacy-arc" id="arrow-127-0-1" stroke-width="2px" d="M245,89.5 C245,2.0 400.0,2.0 400.0,89.5" fill="none" stroke="currentColor"/>\n    <text dy="1.25em" style="font-size: 0.8em; letter-spacing: 1px">\n        <textPath xlink:href="#arrow-127-0-1" class="displacy-label" startOffset="50%" fill="currentColor" text-anchor="middle">nsubj</textPath>\n    </text>\n    <path class="displacy-arrowhead" d="M245,91.5 L237,79.5 253,79.5" fill="currentColor"/>\n</g>\n\n<g class="displacy-arrow">\n    <path class="displacy-arc" id="arrow-127-0-2" stroke-width="2px" d="M420,89.5 C420,2.0 575.0,2.0 575.0,89.5" fill="none" stroke="currentColor"/>\n    <text dy="1.25em" style="font-size: 0.8em; letter-spacing: 1px">\n        <textPath xlink:href="#arrow-127-0-2" class="displacy-label" startOffset="50%" fill="currentColor" text-anchor="middle">attr</textPath>\n    </text>\n    <path class="displacy-arrowhead" d="M575.0,91.5 L583.0,79.5 567.0,79.5" fill="currentColor"/>\n</g>\n</svg>'
```

How can this be rendered as the expected svg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're outputting to HTML, this should work if you have `results='asis'` in the chunk options, so the output is directly interpreted as HTML:

````
```{python, results='asis'}
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("My name is Dhiraj.")
displacy.render(doc)
```
````

Full contents of my working RMarkdown file:

````
---
title: "Python test"
output: html_document
---

```{python, results='asis'}
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("My name is Dhiraj.")
displacy.render(doc)
```
````

Comment: thanks, but even after adding the. `results='asis'`, the output is the same. No svg rendered. In the YAML the output is `html_document`.

Comment: No joy post upgrading to version 1.15. I am on Mac OS. Could that be a problem?

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! After adding the `results='asis'`, I didn't knit the document! I was just trying to execute the code chunk. My bad. However now when I knit it, I see the SVG. Thanks again for your help and patience!